# Multiplication and then sum?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to get a number from an EditText and multiply it by a standard number and then sum it to a number taken from another EditText and also multiply this by a standard number.
Then I have to show the value when I click a Button.

The calculation is: `(editextnumber1 * standardnumber1) + (editextnumber2 * standardnumber2)`

Comment: So what  is the problem in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below code :

```
    EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    int editextnumber = Integer.parseInt(e.getText().toString());
    int standardnumber = 10;  // your own value
    int result = editextnumber*standardnumber;

    // repeat the above procedure twice
```

Comment: Select this answer as correct if your problem is resolved .